# metaタグviewportのwidth=device-960pxはどういった効果があるのでしょうか？

Tags: html5

http://ichimaruni-design.com/2015/01/viewport/

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-960px">
```

上記サイトでViewportのwidthにdevice-960pxを指定しています。
これはどういった効果があるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`device-width`を`960`に直そうとして書き間違えたのではないでしょうか。

`device-960px`という形式は少なくとも[Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)および[Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta)でサポートされていません。